# Windows + D in remote session (MSTSC)?

Tags: windows

How do I execute the equivalent of 'Windows + D' to show the desktop in a remote session (MSTSC)?

I am aware of a few other important ones like 'alt + home' which opens the start menu, but I'd like to find one that sends all windows within a remote session to the taskbar to show only the desktop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the remote desktop client you can configure how the keyboard combinations get passed here:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Thanks. I did some more research and I think this is the only option. I was hoping there was a 'show desktop' shortcut without having to do this, but this is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the remote desktop connection to apply Windows key combinations on the remote computer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are RDCing to a computer that is set up strictly for RDC, then i would just add the Desktop link to the task bar.